# Reading ephemeris data from GPS receiver?

Tags: gps

I want to filter the GPS data. when I use the low cost GPS receiver, it gives erroneous data. therefore I want to apply some filtering technique.

How can I read ephemeris data from GPS receiver?

I need to use ephemeris data for filtering.

Comment: What receiver are you using?

Comment: I've read, that you can do this with open source-/ hardward platforms like the swift piksi, http://docs.swiftnav.com/wiki/Piksi_User_Getting_Started_Guide (Paragraph  -Viewing Position Solutions). What kind of envrionmen do you use?